# How to get Exif Data of image with fineUploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I need the exif Data of images which i uploaded recently. Is there is any method of FineUploader to get this functionality. can i get image properties like GEO-LOCATION, DATE.

Please help me out with this.

Thanks,
Yogesh Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Fine Uploader does ensure EXIF data is transferred from original JPEGs to any scaled versions, it doesn't extract EXIF data from files for you.  This is beyond the scope of an upload library.  If you want to extract this data from one if your files client side, there are other libraries that serve this purpose, such as https://github.com/jseidelin/exif-js.

Comment: Thanks Ray Nicholus,Yes i used this library now its working for me. I used this Function :    EXIF.getData(file, function() {

 console.log(EXIF.exifAll(this));
   }); to get all exif data of images.